# Помогите составить простенькую регулярку

Tags: алгоритм, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день! Прошу помощи у людей, которые более менее знают регулярные выражения

Нужно проверить текст, чтобы он был вот такого вида `А000АА000` ( буквы на кириллице)

тоесть, он может быть `A123BN999` и т.п
0 - цифра
А - буква на кириллице

это, к слову, проверка автомобильного номера

Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень признателен!

Пишу на `Python3`

Comment: `"^[А-Я]\d{3}[А-Я]{2}\d{2,3}$"` ?

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо!!

Comment: Указатели начала и конца строки забыли.

Comment: Если это российские номера, то по идее нужны еще дополнительные условия. В частности, используются не все буквы (той же "Я", например, быть не может), также не бывает номеров с тремя нулями.

Comment: @Yaant спасибо, мне бы сначала хоть какую-то ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Из википедии:](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8)

> Комбинации на стандартных номерных знаках строятся по принципу — 3
>   буквы, 3 цифры. Буквы означают серию номерного знака, а цифры — номер.
>   ГОСТ для использования на знаках разрешены 12 букв кириллицы, имеющие
>   графические аналоги в латинском алфавите — А, В, Е, К, М, Н, О, Р, С,
>   Т, У и Х.

```
^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]\d{3}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}\d{2,3}$
```

[RegEx online](https://regex101.com/r/RHl7sQ/2)

Пример на Python:

```
In [22]: pat
Out[22]: '^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]\\d{3}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}\\d{2,3}$'

In [23]: lst
Out[23]: ['С065МК78', 'Я001ЫЫ001', 'А001НА47']

In [24]: [bool(re.match(pat, txt)) for txt in lst]
Out[24]: [True, False, True]
```